# A Veronese map is a morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is really simple, I'm beginning to study Algebraic Geometry and I'm still struggling to get the basic concepts.

I would like to know if a Veronese map $v_{n,d}:\mathbb P^n\to \mathbb P^N$ is a morphism.

Thanks

Comment: @FredrikMeyer what a morphism means in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A morhism $\varphi:X \to Y$ between two projective varieties is a continous map that pulls back regular functions to regular functions. Explicitly, this means that if $U \subseteq Y$ is an open subset and $f:U \to k$ is a regular function, the composite $f \circ \varphi:\varphi^{-1}(U) \to k$ is also regular.

To check if a map of sets $\varphi:X \to \mathbb P^N$ is a morphism, you can do it locally. That is, let $U_i$ we the standard open cover of $\mathbb P^N$. Then each $U_i$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^{N}$ and has coordinate functions $\{ x_0,\cdots,x_n\}$. Then it is enough to check that each $x_i \circ \varphi:\varphi^{-1}(U_i) \to k$ is regular. (this is basically Lemma 3.6 in Chapter I of Hartshorne)

Now, lets look at your example in the case $n=1,d=2$ (for notational simplicity). Then the Veronese map takes the form $$v(p_0:p_1)=(p_0^2:p_0p_1:p_1^2)$$ for a point $(p_0:p_1) \in \mathbb P ^1$. The inverse images of the sets $U_0,U_1,U_2$ are $\mathbb P^1 \backslash\{p_0=0\}$, $\mathbb P^1 \backslash \{ (0:1),(1:0) \}$ and $\mathbb P^1 \backslash \{ p_1 = 0 \}$, respectively.

Restricted to $U_0$, the Veronese map takes the form $$ v(1:p_1) = (1:p_1:p_1^2),$$  which is clearly regular, because it is a map defined by polynomials from one affine space to another.

The other charts are handled similarly, and it should not be difficult to generalize this to general $n$ and $d$.

Comment: In the first paragraph did you mean $\varphi^{-1}(U)$, instead of $\varphi^{-1}(V)$?

Comment: @user42912: Yes. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Dear Frederik, In the last sentence: "it should be difficult" might be missing the word "not".  Cheers,

Comment: @MattE Thanks! You might be right.

Comment: In order to prove that $\varphi:X\to Y$ is a morphism, why is it enough to prove $\varphi^{-1}:U_i\to k$ is regular for the basic open subsets of $Y$, instead to prove it for the every open subset $U$ of $Y$?

Comment: Excellent explanation:  an explicit  special case  is much clearer that the obscure juggling of indices of the general case.

Comment: @user42912: Dear user, The answer to the question in your comment is that the property of being a morphism is Zariski local on the source.  Consider the following analogous problem: suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is a map between topological spaces.  Prove that the following are equivalent: (a) $f$ is continuous; (b) for every open subset of $U$ of $X$, the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is continuous; (c) there exists an open cover $U_i$ of $X$ such that the restriction of $f$ to each $U_i$ is continuous.   (Hopefully you can do this.)  Now the definition of morphism in algebraic geometry is ...

Comment: ... arranged to that the analogous statement is true, and Fredrik is checking that the Veronese map is a morphism by using criterion (c).  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE using the equivalence you mentioned we prove that the pullback is continuous for every $U$, but what about been regular for every $U$? thanks

Comment: @user42912: Dear user, You have to *strengthen* the equivalence I mentioned, not just apply it literally; i.e. you have to prove the analogous statement with "continuous map" replaced by "morphism" or "regular function". This is an exercise just using the definition.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I'm doing this right now, thanks

Comment: @MattE one last question, I didn't understand why $v$ restricted to $U_0$ is a map defined by polynomials from one affine space to another and where the answerer uses the lemma 3.6 exactly, sorry I'm really new on this subject, regards.

Comment: @user42912: It is a fact that $\mathbb P^n \backslash H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^n$. This is for example Prop 2.2 in Hartshorne.